# Print a multidimensional array as dropdown menu recursively without hardcoding loops in PHP

Tags: php, css, loops, drop-down-menu, multidimensional-array

I have an array in which I keep a menu of more than 100 elements and then print it as a CSS drop-down menu. There are 5 main menus and these have sub-menus, and some of these have sub-menus etc etc. Right now I'm hard coding the loops when printing them, but I'm sure there must be some clever way of doing it in only a few lines of code! This is what the beginning of the array looks like:

```
$menu = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Travel tips',
        'url' => 'travel-tips',
        'sub' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Travel guide',
                'url' => 'travel-guide'),
            array(
                'title' => 'Places to visit',
                'url' => 'places-to-visit',
                'sub' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Ahu Akivi',
                        'url' => 'ahu-akivi'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Ahu Tongariki',
                        'url' => 'ahu-tongariki'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Anakena',
                        'url' => 'anakena'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Orongo',
                        'url' => 'orongo'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Rano Kau',
                        'url' => 'rano-kau'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Rano Raraku',
                        'url' => 'rano-raraku'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Vinapu',
                        'url' => 'vinapu'))),
            array(
                'title' => 'Things to do',
                'url' => 'things-to-do',
                'sub' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Beaches',
                        'url' => 'beaches'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Church',
                        'url' => 'church'),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'Fishing',
                        'url' => 'fishing'),
```

...and then it goes on and on. How can I loop this neatly and cleanly in only a few lines of code recursively without hard-coding the loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to aynber I came up with a solution that also gives correct URLs:

```
function echoMenu($arr, $prevURL)
{
    if (is_array($prevURL))
    {
        foreach($prevURL as $url) //Collect all previous URLs into string
            $prevURLStr .= $url . '/';
    }

    foreach($arr as $key => $subArr)
    {
        echo '<li><a href="/' . $prevURLStr . $subArr['url'] . '">' . $subArr['title'] . '</a>';
        if(!empty($subArr['sub'])) //Has submenu - call function again to enter it
        {
            $prevURL[] = $subArr['url']; //Add this folder's URL to array

            echo '<ul>';
            echoMenu($subArr['sub'], $prevURL);
            echo '</ul>';

            $prevURL = array_pop($prevURL); //Remove last element
            $prevURL = @array_values($prevURL); //Remove empty remains
        } 
        echo '</li>';
    }
}

echo '<ul class="menu">';

echoMenu($menu, null);

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Good you got it to work, but "_only a few lines of code recursively without hard-coding the loops_" ..? :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd want a self-calling function, if you don't want to specify the number of loops. Just add in the div/class/formatting you want in each loop.

```
function echoMenu($arr){
    foreach($arr as $subArr){
        if(!empty($subArr['sub'])){
            echo "<a href='{$subArr['url']}'>{$subArr['title']}</a>";
            echo "<div class='for-sub-links'>";
            echoMenu($subArr['sub']);
            echo "</div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div><a href='{$subArr['url']}'>{$subArr['title']}</a></div>";
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to end line 5 with a semi-colon

Comment: A nice solution, although `recursive` is a more common name for a function that calls itself

Comment: Brain's a little frazzled at the end of the day... would you believe I couldn't think of the word recursive?

Comment: the word recursively is used in the question :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, nice and clean! Though, it has 1 problem. For example, the URL of the button "Ahu Tongariki" should have the URL /travel-tips/places-to-visit/ahu-tongariki/, but with this solution it only has the URL /ahu-tongariki/. I fixed this by adding the current URL to an array $prevURL[] which I then use in the function call - echoMenu($subArr['sub'], $prevURL). I added an answer with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
function recursive_menu($menu) {
  $output ='';
  foreach($menu as $m){
    $output .= '<li><a href="'.$m['url'].'">'.$m['title'].'</a>';
    if (isset($m['sub'])) {
      $output .= '<ul>';
      foreach( $m['sub'] as $item ) {
        $output.=recursive_menu($item);
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
    } 
  }
  return $output.'</li>';  
}
```

then...

```
echo '<ul>'.recursive_menu($menu).'</ul>';
```

something like this...

Answer (score 1):

Rather simple :

```
//mainly for demonstration / test purposes
function drawMenuItem($title, $url, $indent) {
    for ($i=0;$i<=$indent;$i++) echo "___";
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>'.'<br>';
}

//the actual "few lines of code recursively" function
function createMenuRecursively($menu, $indent) {
    foreach($menu as $menuItem){
        drawMenuItem($menuItem['title'], $menuItem['url'], $indent);
        if (is_array($menuItem['sub'])) {
            createMenuRecursively($menuItem['sub'], $indent+1);
        }
    }
}

createMenuRecursively($menu, 1);
```

Just using `$indent` for demonstration. Override `drawMenuItem` to do the `CSS` / `ul` / `li` stuff. The above outputs :

[image]
override